# Is it possible to use a aggregate function over partition by as a case condition in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

Problem statement is to calculate median from a table that has two columns. One specifying a number and the other column specifying the frequency of the number.
For e.g.
Table "Numbers":

| Num | Freq |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 |

This median needs to be found for the flattened array with values:
1,1,1,2,2,2

Query:

```
with ct1 as 
(select num,frequency, sum(frequency) over(order by num) as sf from numbers o)
select case when count(num) over(order by num) = 1 then num 
when count(num) over (order by num) > 1 then sum(num)/2 end median 
    from ct1 b where sf <= (select max(sf)/2 from ct1) or (sf-frequency) <= (select max(sf)/2 from ct1)
```

Is it not possible to use count(num) over(order by num) as the condition in the case statement?

Comment: '==' is not the equality comparison operator in SQL. I think you want to use '='.

Comment: Why not put `count(num) over (order by num)` in the CTE? Then you can use the resulting value in your main query. Just a thought.

Comment: Using `count(num) over (order by num)` is fine. Your problem is the non-analytical `SUM` function. As an aggregate function it requires `group by`  clause. Perhaps `sum(num_ over()/2` will give you what you looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Find the relevant row / 2 rows based of the accumulated frequencies, and take the average of `num`.
The example and Fiddle will also show you the
computations leading to the result.

- If you already know that `num` is unique, `rowid` can be removed from the ORDER BY clauses

---

```
with  
t1 as
(
    select    t.*
             ,nvl(sum(freq) over (order by num,rowid rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding),0)  as freq_acc_sum_1
             ,sum(freq) over (order by num, rowid)                                                         as freq_acc_sum_2
             ,sum(freq) over ()                                                                            as freq_sum
             
    from      t
)
select    t1.*
         ,case 
              when freq_sum/2 between freq_acc_sum_1 and freq_acc_sum_2 
              then 'V' 
          end as relevant_record
          
from      t1

order by  num, rowid
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d55115bc2db464db6a2b75542f412055)

Example:

| ID | NUM | FREQ | FREQ_ACC_SUM_1 | FREQ_ACC_SUM_2 | FREQ_SUM | RELEVANT_RECORD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | 8 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 18 |  |
| 5 | 10 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 18 |  |
| 1 | 29 | 3 | 2 | 5 | 18 |  |
| 6 | 31 | 1 | 5 | 6 | 18 |  |
| 3 | 33 | 2 | 6 | 8 | 18 |  |
| 4 | 41 | 1 | 8 | 9 | 18 | V |
| 9 | 49 | 2 | 9 | 11 | 18 | V |
| 2 | 52 | 1 | 11 | 12 | 18 |  |
| 8 | 56 | 3 | 12 | 15 | 18 |  |
| 10 | 92 | 3 | 15 | 18 | 18 |  |

| MEDIAN |
| --- |
| 45 |

[Fiddle for 1M records](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ca8fcd94f207ea377eba347ffc114694)

Answer (score -1):

You can find the one (or two) middle value(s) and then average:

```sql
SELECT AVG(num) AS median
FROM   (
  SELECT num,
         freq,
         SUM(freq) OVER (ORDER BY num) AS cum_freq,
         (SUM(freq) OVER () + 1)/2 AS median_freq
  FROM   table_name
)
WHERE  cum_freq - freq < median_freq
AND    median_freq < cum_freq + 1
```

Or, expand the values using a `LATERAL` join to a hierarchical query and then use the `MEDIAN` function:

```sql
SELECT MEDIAN(num) AS median
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT LEVEL
         FROM   DUAL
         WHERE  freq > 0
         CONNECT BY LEVEL <= freq
       )
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (Num, Freq) AS
SELECT 1, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 3 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | MEDIAN |
> | --- |
> | 1.5 |

*(Note: For your sample data, there are 6 items, an even number, so the `MEDIAN` will be half way between the value of 3rd and 4rd items; so half way between 1 and 2 = 1.5.)*

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=b713f3276a28495a78e6071670e1a2cc)*

Comment: Brute force solution with tendency to serious performance issues.